# About regressing some variables along with some factors on a DV after a factor analysis

Tags: regression, pca, factor-analysis

I have used 20 variables to extract 4 factors in a factor analysis. Now I want to use the extracted factors (factor scores) as IVs on an outcome variable. Besides I want to include 4 other variables as IVs in the regression which were not used in the factor analysis. That means I want to regress 4 factors and 4 variables (from outside of the FA) as IVs on a DV. Is there any problem in it statistically?

Secondly, if I want to run a separate regression on another DV by using only 2 of the factors (factor scores) and 3 other variables as IVs, is there any problem?

Just to know, if I extracted 4 components from a PCA (Principal Component Analysis) instead, what would be the answers to the same two questions?

Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Factor regressions tend to suffer from the [measurement error downward bias](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584886331). To overcome this, you would need to build a full [structural equation model](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471011711). Sometimes, [regression among factor scores](http://www.citeulike.org/user/ctacmo/article/2663962) may work out, though.

Regression using the principal components also produces biased estimates, as it is an implicit form of [regression shrinkage](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/2348417).